# Listagg for large data and included values in quotes

Tags: database, oracle

I would like to get all the type names of a user seperated in commas and included in single quotes. The problem I have is that &apos ; character is displayed as output instead of '.

## Trial 1

```
SELECT LISTAGG(TYPE_NAME, ''',''') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TYPE_NAME)
  FROM ALL_TYPES
WHERE OWNER = 'USER1';
```

ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result IS more THAN THE maximum SIZE.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.

## Trial 2

```
SELECT '''' || RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,TYPE_NAME,q'$','$' ).EXTRACT('//text()')
       ORDER BY TYPE_NAME).GetClobVal(),q'$','$') AS LIST
  FROM ALL_TYPES
WHERE OWNER = 'USER1';
```

&apos ;TYPE1&apos ;,&apos ;TYPE2&apos ;, ............... ,'TYPE3&apos ;,&apos ;

## Trial 3

```
SELECT
    dbms_xmlgen.CONVERT(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,TYPE_NAME,''',''').EXTRACT('//text()')
          ORDER BY TYPE_NAME).GetClobVal())

                 AS LIST
  FROM ALL_TYPES
WHERE OWNER = 'USER1';
```

TYPE1&amp ;apos ;,&amp ;apos ;TYPE2&amp ;apos ;, ......... ,&amp ;apos ;TYPE3&amp ;apos ;,&amp ;apos ;

I don;t want to call replace function and then make substring as follow

```
With tbla as (
SELECT REPLACE('''' || RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,TYPE_NAME,q'$','$' ).EXTRACT('//text()')
       ORDER BY TYPE_NAME).GetClobVal(),q'$','$'),'&apos;',''') AS LIST
  FROM ALL_TYPES
WHERE OWNER = 'USER1')
select SUBSTR(list, 1, LENGTH(list) - 2)
from tbla;
```

Is there any other way ?

Comment: What do you mean by **The problem I have is that ' character is displayed as output instead of '**? It's the same character, did you mean to complain about something else? There's a few other things I don't understand. For example, even with LISTAGG (let's say the string won't be too long) - you seem to want to include the single-quotes as part of the separator? Do you need the commas surrounded by single quotes, or the TYPE_NAMEs themselves? If the TYPE_NAMEs, then you are doing it wrong; you should `LISTAGG( '''' || TYPE_NAME || '''', ',') ...` Please clarify before we get too far.

Comment: I m sorry &apos ; character is converted automatically to single quote by the editor.

I get &apos instead of '

I want the values with commas and single quotes in order to use them in a pl/sql block 

Such as 
select * from table where type_name in (the_output_I_asked)

Comment: OK, so if TYPE_NAME are `Type1` and `Type2` you want the resulting string to be `'Type1','Type2'`? Also: what editor are you using? And why is it changing your type of quote (from standard single quote to apostrophe or to back-quote or typographical quote or whatever?) Any decent editor should have a setting to turn off such automatic conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`dbms_xmlgen.convert(col, 1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_xmlgen.htm#i1013100) to prevent escaping.

According to Official docs, the second param `flag` is:

> flag
>
> The flag setting; ENTITY_ENCODE (default) for encode, and
>   ENTITY_DECODE for decode.

```
ENTITY_DECODE - 1
ENTITY_ENCODE - 0 default
```

Try this:

```
select 
    ''''||substr(s, 1, length(s) - 2) list
from (
    select
        dbms_xmlgen.convert(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,type_name,''',''')
              order by type_name).extract('//text()').getclobval(), 1) s
    from all_types
    where owner = 'USER1'
);
```

Tested the similar code below with 100000 rows:

```
with t (s) as (
  select level
  from dual
  connect by level < 100000
)
select
  ''''||substr(s, 1, length(s) - 2)
from (
select 
  dbms_xmlgen.convert(xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(E,s,''',''') order by s desc).extract('//text()').getClobVal(), 1) s
from t);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers